# How to handle checkbox edit event in datagrid

Tags: c#, wpf, checkbox, datagrid, click

I'm currently working on project which needs some click event on checkbox in a datagrid.

All columns and rows are generated manually. Last columns of the datagrid contains checkboxs and I want users to check this.When I'm going to check the box an exception occures :

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException' occurred in PresentationFramework.dll
>
> > Additional information: 'EditItem' is not allowed for this view.

Now, is it required any separate click event to handle the click event.

XAML :

```
     <DataGrid x:Name="single_payment" HorizontalAlignment="Left" ColumnWidth="*" Margin="11,87,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="134" Width="261" BorderThickness="0" AutoGenerateColumns="False"/>
```

C# :

```
        /* setting columns */
        DataGridTextColumn c1 = new DataGridTextColumn();
        c1.Header = "#";
        //c1.IsReadOnly = true;
        c1.Width = 10;
        c1.Binding = new Binding("Num");
        single_payment.Columns.Add(c1);
        DataGridTextColumn c2 = new DataGridTextColumn();
        c2.Header = "Name";
        //c1.IsReadOnly = true;
        c2.Binding = new Binding("Start");
        single_payment.Columns.Add(c2);

        DataGridTextColumn c4 = new DataGridTextColumn();
        c4.Header = "Amount";
        //c4.IsReadOnly = true;
        c4.Binding = new Binding("Amt");
        single_payment.Columns.Add(c4);
        
        DataGridCheckBoxColumn c3 = new DataGridCheckBoxColumn();
        c3.Header = "Paid";
        //c3.IsReadOnly = false;
        c3.Binding = new Binding("Finich");
        single_payment.Columns.Add(c3);

        /* Set columns ends here */
        /*  set row  */
        try
        {
            dbconnection c = new dbconnection();
            c.cmd.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM purpose_master WHERE type='otp';";
            c.da.Fill(c.dt);
            if (c.dt.Rows.Count > 0)
            {
                for (int col = 0; col < c.dt.Rows.Count; col++)
                {
                    //MessageBox.Show(col.ToString());
                    single_payment.Items.Add(new Item() { Num = c.dt.Rows[col][0].ToString(), Start = c.dt.Rows[col][1].ToString(), Amt = c.dt.Rows[col][4].ToString(), Finich = "" });
                }
            }
            c.con.Close();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }
        /*   set row end */
```

Comment: You are binding CheckBox.IsChecked to Finich = ""... Think about that again.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In general, Checkbox have the Checked and UnChecked event that might exposed in its Column(`DataGridCheckBoxColumn`). If you need the click event of the Check box control, I suggest you to add a Template Column instead of Checkbox column and add a Check box in a `DataTemplate`. Raise the Click event in that and make use of it..

Comment: Yes, We can use that.But that's exactly what I want. Anyway thanks.

Comment: Thanks god I had a hard time founding this, It's been 4h that i get post about observable collection or other (idk why but this problem oriented me on this and then i could click it but there where massive amount of bug with it !)